# Issue with java checkboxes and functions

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am trying to create a simple checklist program to learn more about checkboxes, my main goal is to check all the boxes, have the frame close, and display a message saying you're done. I tried to have it all nestled in a function for the last part, as the frame and checkboxes seem to work, but found I couldn't write to variables inside of that specific function. I am looking mainly for different options to research, or possibly what I'm missing with my current implementation

```
public static void simpleChecklist(){
        JFrame f= new JFrame("Simple Checklist"); 
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400,400);   
        //JButton done = new JButton();
        //done.setBounds(150,300,50,50);
        //f.add(done);
    
        boolean projectWork = false;
        JCheckBox ProjectWork = new JCheckBox("Project Work", projectWork);  
        ProjectWork.setBounds(100,50, 200,50);  
        boolean math = false;
        JCheckBox Math = new JCheckBox("Math", math);  
        Math.setBounds(100,100, 100,50);  
        boolean science = false;
        JCheckBox Science = new JCheckBox("Science", science);
        Science.setBounds(100,150,100,50);
        boolean compSci = false;
        JCheckBox CompSci = new JCheckBox("Comp Sci", compSci);
        CompSci.setBounds(100,200,100,50);
        boolean english = false;
        JCheckBox English = new JCheckBox("English", english);
        English.setBounds(100,250,100,50);
        boolean gov = false;
        JCheckBox Gov = new JCheckBox("Government", gov);
        Gov.setBounds(100,300,100,50);
        f.add(Gov);
        f.add(English);
        f.add(CompSci);
        f.add(Science);
        f.add(ProjectWork);  
        f.add(Math); 
        /*{done.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               

            }
        });*/


       
         class ItemListen implements ItemListener {

            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    
                Gov.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                English.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                CompSci.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                Science.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                ProjectWork.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                Math.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
               // Different Get Methods from ActionEvent
               /* arg0.getItemSelectable()
                arg0.getStateChange()
                arg0.getItem()*/
               
    
            }
    
        }
        boolean govDone = false;
        boolean englishDone = false;
        boolean compSciDone = false;
        boolean scienceDone = false;
        boolean projectWorkDone = false;
        boolean mathDone = false;


        if(Math.isSelected()){
            mathDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        if(ProjectWork.isSelected()){
            projectWorkDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if(Science.isSelected()){
            scienceDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if(English.isSelected()){
            englishDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if(Gov.isSelected()){
            govDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if(CompSci.isSelected()){
            compSciDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        

    }
    private static void checkIfDone(boolean projectWorkDone, boolean mathDone, boolean scienceDone,JFrame f, boolean compSciDone, boolean englishDone, boolean govDone){

        if (projectWorkDone == true && mathDone == true && scienceDone == true && compSciDone == true && englishDone == true && govDone == true){
            closeWindow(f);
            
        }
    }
    private static void closeWindow(JFrame f){
        f.dispose();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congrats! You Finished Your Work!!!");
    }
```

Comment: You are doing quite a few things incorrectly.  Mainly, don't add your listeners in your `itemStateChanged `method.  That's the method the listeners call so you need to have  the  `Listeners` installed prior to using the checkboxes or the method will never be invoked.  I highly recommend  you check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) which gives many examples of how to implement various listeners.  Click on the `Big Index` and check the topics.

Comment: I second what WJS stated: You need to understand the basic of Events, and how Event Listeners work. Also, this might sound like common sense, but you need to remember that component can react to multiple events and sometimes, these events are related to each other (or can happen simultaneously). For example, mouse click events can be tricky sometimes if you don't fully grasp this concept.

Comment: Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct, others are not. Be consistent!

Comment: AND... don't repeat similar variable names. That's so confusing. For example `projectWork` (boolean) and `ProjectWork` (JCheckBox).

Comment: @WJS im having trouble navigating the site, for now I've just scrapped all of my work trying to listen to the checkboxes, and am back to the basics of the check boxes open and functionally work, is there a good way if listening to them all, and triggering an event once all have been checked?

Comment: @WJS I had an idea of just having a "done" button that would do the check but IM curious about other methods, but will fall back on the button if all else fails

Comment: "is there a good way if listening to them all?" Typically, this is not a good idea. There is physically no way you could select all of the checkboxes simultaneously unless you have a "check all" checkbox. In this case, you only care about that SINGLE event and not the collective subsequent selection of the individual check boxes that are selected. 99.99% of the time, you want each component to handle the event it is responsible for.

Comment: Also, if you want to be alerted once all check boxes change to the "selected" state, the best thing to do is have an Event Listener to handle whatever needs to happen when a check box is selected (i.e. write some text in a text area) AND a component OBSERVER responsible to monitor the state of your check boxes so that it could trigger some event when the observer observes that all check boxes are in the "selected" state. These are two separate problems if you really thing about it. Therefore, handling those problems are the responsibility of different entities. Separate their responsibilities.

Comment: @AndrewDawson check the answer MadProgrammer posted. Read his first comment about simplifying your requirements. This is normally called "problem decomposition" which is breaking a big problem into smaller problems and solving each one independently. I wrote a blog about this about 9 years ago. I suggest you look into it https://www.professorfontanez.com/2012/01/the-importance-of-problem-decomposition.html. It is a very simple problem but I think the lesson is well illustrated there.

Answer (score 1):

Start by having a look at...

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

When you start learning something new, start by simplifying your requirements.  Start with working out how to use a single `JCheckBox`, figure out how to react to it's changes and understand it's basic workflow, then add a second and third checkbox and see how those things change, then add in the other requirements as you go.

[image: Simple]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            JCheckBox projectWork = new JCheckBox("Project Work", false);
            JCheckBox math = new JCheckBox("Math", false);
            JCheckBox science = new JCheckBox("Science", false);
            JCheckBox compSci = new JCheckBox("Comp Sci", false);
            JCheckBox english = new JCheckBox("English", false);
            JCheckBox gov = new JCheckBox("Government", false);

            add(projectWork, gbc);
            add(math, gbc);
            add(science, gbc);
            add(compSci, gbc);
            add(english, gbc);
            add(gov, gbc);

            JCheckBox checkBoxes[] = new JCheckBox[] {
                projectWork, math, science, compSci, english, gov
            };
            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    boolean completed = true;
                    for (JCheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
                        if (!cb.isSelected()) {
                            completed = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (completed) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "All your class belong to us");
                        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this).dispose();
                    }
                }
            };
            for (JCheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
                cb.addActionListener(listener);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void simpleChecklist() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Simple Checklist");
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        //JButton done = new JButton();
        //done.setBounds(150,300,50,50);
        //f.add(done);

        boolean projectWork = false;
        JCheckBox ProjectWork = new JCheckBox("Project Work", projectWork);
        ProjectWork.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 50);
        boolean math = false;
        JCheckBox Math = new JCheckBox("Math", math);
        Math.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 50);
        boolean science = false;
        JCheckBox Science = new JCheckBox("Science", science);
        Science.setBounds(100, 150, 100, 50);
        boolean compSci = false;
        JCheckBox CompSci = new JCheckBox("Comp Sci", compSci);
        CompSci.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 50);
        boolean english = false;
        JCheckBox English = new JCheckBox("English", english);
        English.setBounds(100, 250, 100, 50);
        boolean gov = false;
        JCheckBox Gov = new JCheckBox("Government", gov);
        Gov.setBounds(100, 300, 100, 50);
        f.add(Gov);
        f.add(English);
        f.add(CompSci);
        f.add(Science);
        f.add(ProjectWork);
        f.add(Math);
        /*{done.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            }
        });*/

        class ItemListen implements ItemListener {

            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {

                Gov.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                English.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                CompSci.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                Science.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                ProjectWork.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                Math.addItemListener(new ItemListen());
                // Different Get Methods from ActionEvent
                /* arg0.getItemSelectable()
                arg0.getStateChange()
                arg0.getItem()*/

            }

        }
        boolean govDone = false;
        boolean englishDone = false;
        boolean compSciDone = false;
        boolean scienceDone = false;
        boolean projectWorkDone = false;
        boolean mathDone = false;

        if (Math.isSelected()) {
            mathDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        if (ProjectWork.isSelected()) {
            projectWorkDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if (Science.isSelected()) {
            scienceDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if (English.isSelected()) {
            englishDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if (Gov.isSelected()) {
            govDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }
        if (CompSci.isSelected()) {
            compSciDone = true;
            checkIfDone(projectWorkDone, mathDone, scienceDone, f, compSciDone, englishDone, govDone);
        }

    }

    private static void checkIfDone(boolean projectWorkDone, boolean mathDone, boolean scienceDone, JFrame f, boolean compSciDone, boolean englishDone, boolean govDone) {

        if (projectWorkDone == true && mathDone == true && scienceDone == true && compSciDone == true && englishDone == true && govDone == true) {
            closeWindow(f);

        }
    }

    private static void closeWindow(JFrame f) {
        f.dispose();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats! You Finished Your Work!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You had me at "When you start learning something new, start by simplifying your requirements" LOL

Comment: @hfontanez This is basically how I live - I have so many "grand ideas", but if I tried to implement as a whole, I'd probably end up killing myself :P

Comment: I believe in reincarnation because I have killed myself many times over for not doing this LOL

Comment: @hfontanez ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is version of what you wanted to do. It is simpler as it uses a layout manager to align the checkboxes.  The threads complicate matters and aren't completely necessary as I will explain later.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ItemListenerDemo extends JPanel implements ItemListener {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Listener Demo");
    String[] subjects = { "CompSci", "Math", "History", "Sociology",
            "Chemistry" };
    int checkCount = 0;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities
                .invokeLater(() -> new ItemListenerDemo().start());
    }
    // basic boiler plate
    public void start() {
        // add the panel to the frame
        f.add(this); 
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
        // resize and position the components
        f.pack();

        // BoxLayout will align them from top to bottom.
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // install the checkboxes
        // add the subject, the listener, and add to the panel
        for (String subject : subjects) {
            JCheckBox b = new JCheckBox(subject);
            b.addItemListener(this);
            add(b); // add to panel
        }
        // center on screen
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        // wait for a signal to check and see if all boxes are checked
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    }
                    if (checkCount == subjects.length) {
                        int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                "Congrats! You Finished Your Work!!!\n Do you want to quit?");
                        if (action == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
    
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
    
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JCheckBox) {
            JCheckBox b = (JCheckBox) source;
            // adjust the checkCount based on this checkboxes status.
            checkCount += b.isSelected() ? 1 : -1;
            // signal those threads waiting.
            synchronized (this) {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the thread is two fold.

Notice my `SwingUtilities` statement.  That starts the whole process in the EDT which includes the `while(true)` loop.  So the EDT would never exit since the loop would never end.  The loop waits for the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) to finish it's business and then have the other thread check the status of the `checkCount`.  If I had done this check in the `itemStateChanged` method, the last checkbox would not have `visibly appeared to be checked` since I was still in the EDT and the painting could not finish.